# Identify this image of a metallic castle or fortress that has a radar dish and a skull with a green "W" on its forehead

Tags: story-identification, origins

I recently attended BrickCon 2015 in Seattle and saw this outstanding mosaic. It's roughly 5 feet tall and 7 feet wide. However, I have no idea what the mosaic is. It looks cartoonish, but I don't recognize it. Please identify what this mosaic is based on. [image: LEGO]

Comment: For what its worth, [google image search](https://www.google.com/imghp?) nails this one - click the  camera icon in the search bar and paste a URL to this image.

Comment: _"Identify this image of a metallic castle or fortress that has a radar dish and a skull with a green “W” on its forehead"_  I don't know what I was expecting when I clicked on this.  But I guess I got it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's Dr. Wily's Castle from [Mega Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega_Man).

[image: _Dr. Wily's Castle_]

If you want, here are some other images of it (linking to pages, so you get detail, rather than just posting images):

- http://archive.wired.com/geekdad/2008/08/dr-wilys-castle/
- http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/323184
- http://smashbros-miiverse.com/stages/dr-wily-castle

and Ty Keltner, the builders video [interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1zeC-0usNe8&feature=youtu.be):

Comment: Mega Man 2 actually. Gosh I played that game. Just looking at the picture makes the 8-bit song ring in my head.

Answer (score 5):

thanks for coming to BrickCon.

This piece is by Ty Keltner, a Lego builder from Juneau, Alaska. You're right about the subject matter. That's Wily Castle from the 1988 video game Mega Man 2. You're pretty close on the dimensions too, it is exactly 60 inches by 80 inches. Ty built it in his garage over the course of a year.

You can find more of his stuff here, though it doesn't look like it has been updated in a while: http://www.mocpages.com/home.php/34777

Comment: lol. We've probably met. I sat across from his mosaic for the entire con. Just didn't get close enough to read the fine print.